# Error when loading rpy2 with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, rpy2

I am trying to load `rpy2` inside a project where I am working with `anaconda` and I am getting a surprising error for which I cannot find a solution.
My python version is `3.4`, my anaconda version is `3.17.0` - I am using a Mac (OSX Yosemite version 10.10.4)

`R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"`

`Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2 (64-bit)`

```py
try:
    from rpy2 import robjects
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
```

I am getting this error message

> dlopen(/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so,
> 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib   Referenced from:
>
> /Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
> Reason: image not found

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just built an updated rpy2 2.7.0 against R 3.2.2. Can you run

```
conda install -c r rpy2
```

and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @asmeurer -- I have the exact same issue and installing rpy2 as you outlined doesn't fix it. I just upgraded to Mac OSX 10.11, my Python version is 'Python 2.7.10', conda: '3.18.4', R: 'R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"' -- I have updated all conda packages, installed r-essentials, and everything else I can imagine

Comment: I created a new question as I think this might be a more complex issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672565/rpy2-error-after-upgrading-to-osx-el-capitan

Comment: installing with conda i got https://gist.github.com/88bf9ed4f9234a2c88ea
that seems related to rpy2 version (bug fixed in 2.7.4, conda seems to install 2.7.0):  https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/313/typeerror-type-rpy2rinterfacestrsexpvector

Comment: Thank you @asmeurer! You saved me a lot of time

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for using rpy2 with an r-conda environment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126077/use-rpy2-with-packages-installed-in-r-conda-environment