# rpy2 error after upgrading to OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rpy2, osx-elcapitan

I have an error occurring in a [very similar way to this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602578/error-when-loading-rpy2-with-anaconda/32617616#32617616) The solution of simply installing `rpy2` using conda doesn't work.

The key difference in my case is that `rpy2` worked properly before I updated to Mac OSX 10.11 (El Capitan). My Python version is `Python 2.7.10`, conda: `3.18.4`, R: `R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety` and all were installed using the anaconda distribution.

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
Reason: image not found
```

when trying to load the `rpy2.ipython` extension:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

I have a hunch it is a fix similar to [this question dealing with loading the `rJava` R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite).

Comment: so I assume you already tried reinstalling?

Comment: I reinstalled R a couple times, but not anaconda -- I'll do that!

Comment: That worked. I feel dumb now.

Comment: I actually assumed you would only reinstall condas version of `rpy2` and `r`, but this also works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling everything from scratch fixed the error.