# Anaconda import error for rpy2

Tags: anaconda, python-3.5, rpy2

I have a problem with using rpy2 on Anaconda Python. The issue is that it fails to import due to the following TypeError:

> TypeError: type 'rpy2.rinterface.StrSexpVector' is not an acceptable
>   base type

My python version is `3.5`, my anaconda version is `4.0.0`, my rpy2 version is `2.7.0`.

The problem seems to be that Anaconda now uses version 3.5 which is not compatible with rpy2 2.7.3 or lower, see https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/313/typeerror-type-rpy2rinterfacestrsexpvector - as Anaconda currently default installs 2.7.0  the import fails. How can this issue be fixed?

The issue is similar to the one asked here, [Error when loading rpy2 with anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602578/error-when-loading-rpy2-with-anaconda), however, the old solution of installing 2.7.0 is no longer compatible as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be on OS X, I've built Conda packages for rpy2 2.8.0 which you can get with:

```
conda install -c ijstokes rpy2=2.8.0
```

These are available for Python 2.7 and 3.5.  The problem stems from this rpy2 bug which has now been fixed: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/313/typeerror-type-rpy2rinterfacestrsexpvector

If you're not on OS X, then you can build your own version with something like:

```
conda skeleton pypi rpy2 --version=2.8.0 --python=3.5
conda build rpy2
conda install --use-local rpy2
```

Those commands are from memory, but they should work or be close enough you can figure out the exact options.